# visual studo 22 CMakePresets are missing in wsl 2

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2022, wsl-2

I am using VS22 and wanted to start using CMakePresets for my configs. On windows everything works well and i get the expected config and build presets.

[image]

But when selecting my WSL 2 I don't get any configs
[image]

It offers me to use a CppProperties file, but i would like to use the CMakePresets file.
My `CMakePresets.json` is:

```
  {
    "version": 4,
    "cmakeMinimumRequired": {
      "major": 3,
      "minor": 17,
      "patch": 0
    },
    "configurePresets": [
      {
        "name": "base",
        "hidden": true,
        "toolchainFile": "./cmake/toolchain.cmake",
        "generator": "Ninja",
        "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/out/${presetName}",
        "architecture": {
          "value": "x64",
          "strategy": "external"
        }
      },
      {
        "inherits": "base",
        "name": "p-win-dbg",
        "displayName": "p-win-dbg",
        "cacheVariables": { "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug" }
      },
      {
        "inherits": "base",
        "name": "p-win-rel",
        "displayName": "p-win-rel",
        "cacheVariables": { "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release" }
      },
      {
        "inherits": "base",
        "name": "p-lx-dbg",
        "displayName": "p-lx-dbg",
        "cacheVariables": { "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug" }
      },
      {
        "inherits": "base",
        "name": "p-lx-rel",
        "displayName": "p-lx-rel",
        "cacheVariables": { "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release" }
      }
    ],
    "buildPresets": [
      {
        "name": "p-win-dbg",
        "configurePreset": "p-win-dbg"
      },
      {
        "name": "p-win-rel",
        "configurePreset": "p-win-rel"
      },
      {
        "name": "p-lx-dbg",
        "configurePreset": "p-lx-dbg"
      },
      {
        "name": "p-lx-rel",
        "configurePreset": "p-lx-rel"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I also tired adding conditions for the OS and setting

```
  "vendor": {
    "microsoft.com/VisualStudioRemoteSettings/CMake/1.0": {
      "forceWSL1Toolset": true
    }
  }
```

for the WSL targets.

What do i need to do to make CMakePresets work for WSL 2?

(With `CMakeSettings.json` and VS19 everything worked as expected. But this is a VS specific file and does not work with any other IDE.)